# Using accessor method of DESeq2 in rpy2

Tags: r, bioinformatics, rpy2

I am trying to use DESeq2 package through rpy2. Overall, it works fine, but I am struggling with using accessor function. 
Specifically, I have a sample data frame `tcdf` and counts data frame `access_tcdf` that I convert to R objects by

```
rtcdf = pandas2ri.py2ri_pandasdataframe(tcdf)
raccess_tcdf = pandas2ri.py2ri_pandasdataframe(access_tcdf)
```

and I create a DESeq_DataSet by

```
ddsMat = deseq2.DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = raccess_tcdf,
                              colData = rtcdf,
                              design = Formula("~ replicate + strain + time"))
```

**The sticking point is how I can supply predefined normalization factors in rpy2**? I have a data frame of per gene normalization factors `rnorm_factor` and in R I would normally do:

```
normalizationFactors( ddsMat ) <- data.matrix(norm_factor)
```

but I don't understand how and if I can call normalizationFactors function from rpy2.

When I tried:

```
deseq2.normalizationFactors(ddsMat,bdm)
```

I got RRuntimeError:

```
 Error in .local(object, ...) : 
 unused argument (c(0.401314864917528, 0.375673211527775, ...
```

I would appreciate suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening in R is that the call

```
normalizationFactors( ddsMat ) <- data.matrix(norm_factor)
```

is equivalent to

```
ddsMat <- `normalizationFactors<-`(ddsMat, data.matrix(norm_factor))
```

If this is just setting an attribute in an R S4 class instance you can use the strategy described in the documentation (https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/notebooks/s4class.html#class-attributes) otherwise the strategy used by rpy2 itself to implement `names(foo) <- bar` can be used (see [here](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/32439f70fc13401aa2770d0e69eba0526f52529e/rpy/robjects/vectors.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#vectors.py-296)).